# Kuroko2: ジョブの実行が行えない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

#### 環境

Ubuntu 16.04
　Kuroko2 0.4.6
　ruby 2.2.7
　rails 5.2.0

#### 問題

http://tracpath.com/works/devops/how-to-install-kuroko2/
上記URLを参考にKuroko2(v0.4.6)の導入を試みていますが、
URLの手順通りにジョブ作成しLaunchで起動するも実行されません。
（ステータスがWORKINGのままで、実行ログに何も表示されない）

`execute: ashdfhasdf`のような、無意味な文字列で意図的に失敗させるようなスクリプトを記述し、slackに失敗通知を送信させる設定にしても何の反応もありません。

#### log/development.log

```
04:35:28 rails.1     | Started GET "/definitions/3/instances/10/logs" for 150.249.198.207 at 2018- 
07-27 04:35:28 +0000
04:35:28 rails.1     | Started GET "/definitions/3/instances/10/tokens" for 150.249.198.207 at 2018-07-27 04:35:28 +0000
04:35:28 rails.1     | Started GET "/definitions/3/instances/10/execution_logs" for 150.249.198.207 at 2018-07-27 
04:35:28 +0000
04:35:28 rails.1     | Processing by Kuroko2::ExecutionLogsController#index as JSON
04:35:28 rails.1     |   Parameters: {"job_definition_id"=>"3", "job_instance_id"=>"10"}
04:35:28 rails.1     | Processing by Kuroko2::TokensController#index as */*
04:35:28 rails.1     |   Parameters: {"job_definition_id"=>"3", "job_instance_id"=>"10"}
04:35:28 rails.1     | Processing by Kuroko2::LogsController#index as */*
04:35:28 rails.1     |   Parameters: {"job_definition_id"=>"3", "job_instance_id"=>"10"}
04:35:28 rails.1     |   Kuroko2::User Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  `kuroko2_users`.* FROM `kuroko2_users` WHERE `kuroko2_users`.`suspended_at` IS NULL AND `kuroko2_users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
04:35:28 rails.1     |   ? /home/kuroko/.rbenv/versions/2.2.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
04:35:28 rails.1     |   Kuroko2::User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `kuroko2_users`.* FROM `kuroko2_users` WHERE `kuroko2_users`.`suspended_at` IS NULL AND `kuroko2_users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
04:35:28 rails.1     |   ? /home/kuroko/.rbenv/versions/2.2.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
04:35:28 rails.1     |   Kuroko2::User Load (4.5ms)  SELECT  `kuroko2_users`.* FROM `kuroko2_users` WHERE `kuroko2_users`.`suspended_at` IS NULL AND `kuroko2_users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
04:35:28 rails.1     |   ? /home/kuroko/.rbenv/versions/2.2.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
04:35:28 rails.1     |   Kuroko2::JobDefinition Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  `kuroko2_job_definitions`.* FROM `kuroko2_job_definitions` WHERE `kuroko2_job_definitions`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
04:35:28 rails.1     |   ? /home/kuroko/.rbenv/versions/2.2.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
04:35:28 rails.1     |   Kuroko2::JobDefinition Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `kuroko2_job_definitions`.* FROM `kuroko2_job_definitions` WHERE `kuroko2_job_definitions`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
04:35:28 rails.1     |   ? /home/kuroko/.rbenv/versions/2.2.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord- 
5.2.0/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
04:35:28 rails.1     |   Kuroko2::JobDefinition Load (3.1ms)  SELECT  `kuroko2_job_definitions`.* FROM `kuroko2_job_definitions` WHERE `kuroko2_job_definitions`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
04:35:28 rails.1     |   ? /home/kuroko/.rbenv/versions/2.2.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
04:35:28 rails.1     |   Kuroko2::JobInstance Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `kuroko2_job_instances`.* FROM `kuroko2_job_instances` WHERE `kuroko2_job_instances`.`id` = 10 LIMIT 1
04:35:28 rails.1     |   ? /home/kuroko/.rbenv/versions/2.2.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
04:35:28 rails.1     |   Kuroko2::JobInstance Load (2.9ms)  SELECT  `kuroko2_job_instances`.* FROM `kuroko2_job_instances` WHERE `kuroko2_job_instances`.`id` = 10 LIMIT 1
04:35:28 rails.1     |   ? /home/kuroko/.rbenv/versions/2.2.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord- 
5.2.0/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
04:35:28 rails.1     |   Kuroko2::JobInstance Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  `kuroko2_job_instances`.* FROM `kuroko2_job_instances` WHERE `kuroko2_job_instances`.`id` = 10 LIMIT 1
04:35:28 rails.1     |   ? /home/kuroko/.rbenv/versions/2.2.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord- 
5.2.0/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
04:35:28 rails.1     | Completed 404 Not Found in 28ms (ActiveRecord: 6.7ms)
04:35:28 rails.1     |
04:35:28 rails.1     |
04:35:28 rails.1     |   Kuroko2::Log Load (3.8ms)  SELECT `kuroko2_logs`.* FROM `kuroko2_logs` WHERE `kuroko2_logs`.`job_instance_id` = 10 ORDER BY `kuroko2_logs`.`id` ASC
04:35:28 rails.1     |   ? /home/kuroko/.rbenv/versions/2.2.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
04:35:28 rails.1     | Completed 200 OK in 28ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 9.0ms)
04:35:28 rails.1     |
04:35:28 rails.1     |
04:35:28 rails.1     |   Rendering /home/kuroko/.rbenv/versions/2.2.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/kuroko2-0.4.6/app/views/kuroko2/tokens/index.html.slim
04:35:28 rails.1     |   Kuroko2::Token Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `kuroko2_tokens`.* FROM `kuroko2_tokens` WHERE `kuroko2_tokens`.`job_instance_id` = 10
04:35:28 rails.1     |   ? /home/kuroko/.rbenv/versions/2.2.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
04:35:28 rails.1     |    (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `kuroko2_tokens` WHERE `kuroko2_tokens`.`parent_id` = 8
04:35:28 rails.1     |   ? /home/kuroko/.rbenv/versions/2.2.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
04:35:28 rails.1     |   Kuroko2::Execution Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `kuroko2_executions`.* FROM `kuroko2_executions` WHERE `kuroko2_executions`.`token_id` = 8 LIMIT 1
04:35:28 rails.1     |   ? /home/kuroko/.rbenv/versions/2.2.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
04:35:28 rails.1     |   Rendered /home/kuroko/.rbenv/versions/2.2.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/kuroko2-0.4.6/app/views/kuroko2/tokens/index.html.slim (181.0ms)
04:35:28 rails.1     | Completed 200 OK in 213ms (Views: 200.1ms | ActiveRecord: 6.6ms)
```

上記のログを繰り返し吐き続けていますが、railsの知識が乏しいこともあり解決に至っておりません。

どなたか原因等わかる方いらっしゃいましたら、お力添えいただきたく存じます。

Comment: `Kuroko2`をどのうように起動されたのでしょうか? `foreman start`でしょうか?

Comment: @user28902 
コメントありがとうございます。 ```foreman start``` で実行していましたが、どうやらWorkerが起動できていなかったためにジョブの実行ができなかったようです。また、こちらの質問ですが、環境を構築し直しKuroko2の ```v0.5.0``` を導入することでジョブの実行を行うことができました。